# Can not read the specific values of json file in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, filepath, jsonreader

I have downloaded the json files in my App Folder and I want to read that files from my App Folder to print specific values.

Files are located like this : `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/63E66EE9-9A1B-4D4D-AEF6-F8C54D159ED0/Library/NoCloud/MyApp/MyFolder/DTS.json`

This is what file contains: [{"value":0}]
However the file contents are read and printed in console as I have mentioned below but when I read specific value it gives null

```
NSURL *libraryDirURL = [[NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *urlDTSK = [libraryDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NoCloud/MyApp/MyFolder/DTS.json"];
NSString *filePathDTS = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlDTSK encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"This is Dts PATH %@", filePathDTS);
NSData *dataDTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathDTS];
NSLog(@"here is DTS data  %@", dataDTS); //this shows null
NSDictionary *jsonDTS = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataDTS options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"here is jason DTS %@", jsonDTS);
NSMutableArray *DTSvalue = [jsonDTS valueForKeyPath: @"Value"];
DTSValueIs = DTSvalue[0];
NSLog(@"here is DTS Value first%@", DTSvalue[0]);
NSLog(@"here is DTS value is%@", DTSValueIs);
```

This shows `This is Dts contents [{"value":0}]
2018-06-11 17:04:40.940006+0500 Muslims 365[3356:819935] here is DTS data  (null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you are getting an `NSString` from a file URL and then you are getting `NSData` from **that string** as file path which cannot work. Omit that step:

```
NSURL *libraryDirURL = [[NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *urlDTSK = [libraryDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NoCloud/MyApp/MyFolder/DTS.json"];
NSData *dataDTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: urlDTSK];
```

By the way the retrieved JSON is an array, you get the value for key `Value` from the first element which seems to be a numeric value (`NSNumber`).

And handle the error!

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataDTS options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error) { NSLog(@"%@", error); }
NSNumber *dtsValue = jsonArray[0][@"value"];
NSLog(@"here is DTS value: %@", dtsValue); // here is DTS value: 0
```

Comment: still null  no value I am getting

Comment: Check the file URL. Is the file really in a subfolder of the **Library** folder?

Comment: yes its `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/63E66EE9-9A1B-4D4D-AEF6-F8C54D159ED0/Library/NoCloud/MyApp/MyFolder/DTS.json`

Comment: `dataDTS` is `null` or `dtsValue` is `null`? I edited the answer because the key `value` is lowercased.

Comment: tried you updated solution but still its null dtsValue is that I am not defining main bundle path??

Comment: The main bundle and the library folder are two completely different locations.

Comment: ok got it thank, but any solution how ca I get values of my json file?

Comment: Once again, does `dataDTS` contain something? If yes please add the data dump to your question.

Comment: yes its prints `here is DTS data  <5b7b2276 616c7565 223a307d 5d>`

Comment: Good. The code in my answer is supposed to work. I added the missing `@` characters in front of the literal strings and tested the code. It prints *here is DTS value: 0*

Comment: I added too early in warnings

Comment: `here is DTS data < what are these numbers inside >`.  yes its DTSdata prints here is DTS data`<5b7b2276 616c7565 223a307d 5d>`

Comment: in JSON all it keys acts as strings despite if what it contains like `"12go%23"`  this key is a string value in json I think?, but I am getting block of random values instead of a string in json why? like `DTSdata prints here is DTS data<5b7b2276 616c7565 223a307d 5d>` would you help plz?

Comment: `<5b7b2276 616c7565 223a307d 5d>` is clearly `[{"value":0}]`. I have no idea where the random value comes from.

Answer (score 1):

So `libraryDirURL` is a path to library. Then `urlDTSK` is a path to specific file in in the library. Then `filePathDTS` is CONTENTS of that file in library as UTF8 string...

But `dataDTS` is contents of file at location written in file at `filePathDTS`. I believe the code should be:

```
NSData *dataDTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: urlDTSK.path];
```

Comment: `urlDTSK.path` is not evaluating that `.path` what is .path?

Comment: @Max It should give you the path to the file. In your case a file path. You could also change constructor and use `NSURL` directly by writing `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlDTSK]`. So basically `.path` was there just to convert `NSURL` to `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you must allocate

NSMutableArray *DTSvalue = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

before use.

Comment: No, you must not. But the result of `valueForKeyPath` is not even a mutable array.

Comment: The result is an array of dictionary. From his example code it will not get any values, it shows NULL.